# GnuCOBOL calling Rust: libcob: error: module not found

Tags: rust, cobol, gnucobol

I want to call Rust from GnuCOBOL. I've copied the code from the first example in [Can GnuCOBOL interface with Rust?](https://gnucobol.sourceforge.io/faq/index.html#can-gnucobol-interface-with-rust) from Brian Tiffin's GNUCobol FAQ as a test but got an error when running it.

Expected:

```
$ make -B
rustc --crate-type=dylib called.rs
LD_RUN_PATH=. cobc -xj caller.cob -L. -lcalled
:Hello, world:
```

Actual:

```
$ make -B
rustc --crate-type=dylib called.rs
LD_RUN_PATH=. cobc -xj caller.cob -L. -lcalled
libcob: error: module 'hello_rust' not found
make: *** [makefile:5: caller] Error 1
```

I get the same error after compiling both files from the command line, then using `$ ./caller`.

The syntax seems correct based on the `cobc` man page and the linkage sections of the [GnuCOBOL manual](https://gnucobol.sourceforge.io/doc/gnucobol.html#Multiple-sources) and [Rust reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/linkage.html). I've tried `$ ./caller COB_LIBRARY_PATH=.` as described in the GnuCOBOL manual, but it doesn't make a difference. The Rust source compiles to a library as expected, but the COBOL doesn't find it.

Using `$ cobcrun caller` instead displays `libcob: error: module 'caller' not found`.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69960393/libcob-module-getsum-not-found-cobol) question about a similar error is about statically linking multiple COBOL source files, which works fine, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46900457/gnucobol-opencobol-error-libcob-module-not-found) question about a similar error seems to be an issue with `X"AF"`, which isn't used here. Statically linking C source with Jay Moseley's [C Wrapper for Calling Library Function](https://www.jaymoseley.com/gnucobol/cwrapper.html) example works as expected. Statically linking Rust source isn't supported.

Software Versions:

- Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
- cobc (GnuCOBOL) 3.1.2.0
- rustc 1.64.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue seems to be that the COBOL `caller` executable is trying to dynamically load a library named `hello_rust.so` instead of `libcalled.so` at runtime.

- The easy fix without modifying anything is to just create a symlink:

  ```
  $ ln -s libcalled.so hello_rust.so
  ```
- Alternatively, adding `-fstatic` to the `cobc` command should statically link the Rust library at compilation, eliminating the dynamic library runtime calls.

  The example `Makefile` can be updated to look like this:

  ```
  # GnuCOBOL and Rust
  .RECIPEPREFIX = >

  caller: caller.cob libcalled.so
  > LD_RUN_PATH=. cobc -fstatic -xj caller.cob -L. -lcalled

  libcalled.so: called.rs
  > rustc --crate-type=dylib called.rs
  ```

---

For reference, we can investigate what the executable is doing via strace to see what system calls the COBOL runtime is making -- and in our case -- what files it's failing to find.

```
$ strace ./caller 2>&1 | grep hello_rust                                                                                                                                         
access("./hello_rust.so", R_OK)         = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/usr/lib64/gnucobol/hello_rust.so", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, "module 'hello_rust' not found", 29module 'hello_rust' not found) = 29
```

Comment: Perfect answer. Two additions for static calls/linking: you can make any specific call static if doing `CALL STATIC "prog"` - this has the benefit that you can decide in the code what's done. And _very likely_ that whole part would not be needed - because the library was specified at link time - if you tell the system linker to not drop references that are not directly used, which should be `-Q -Wl,--no-as-needed`.
Another option would be to let the COBOL runtime pre-load the module with `COB_PRE_LOAD=libcalled ./hello_rust`.